# How can I prevent the last argument from needing to be quoted with clap?

Tags: rust, clap

I'm using clap and I get a unexpected behaviour when trying to parse arguments.

My command line tool is supposed to work like this

```
foo -u <user> <command>
```

e.g.:

```
foo -u jack echo s
foo -u paul ls -al
```

I need to get options such as user, but the `<command>` itself, I need to be the rest of the args.

The code below results in a behavior where I can't get the value of `<command>` unless it is quoted:

```
foo -u jack echo s
```

```
error: Found argument 's' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

Whereas this works fine:

```
foo -u jack 'echo s'
```

Is there any way of avoiding the quotes?

```rust
let matches = App::new("foo")
    .version("0.1")
    .arg(
        Arg::with_name("user")
            .short("u")
            .long("user")
            .required(true)
            .takes_value(true),
    )
    .arg(
        Arg::with_name("command")
            .help("The command to run")
            .required(true)
            .takes_value(true),
    )
    .get_matches();
```

I've also opened an [issue on the clap repository](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/1344).

Comment: Please take this opportunity to commit to a choice between `system(3)` semantics that expect a single argument with a shell command (like `su`, `ssh` and `parallel`) and `execve(2)` semantics that expect multiple separate arguments (like `sudo`, `xargs`, `find`). Don't try to accept both versions, it's only fragile and confusing.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'll read about it! Thanks for the info! I was aware of such patterns but unaware they had name/specifications. Awesome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, clap will only parse any argument once. This means that in `-u jack echo s`, it will parse `-u jack` as the "user" option, `echo` as the "command" argument, and have an argument `s` that it doesn't know what to do with (hence it "wasn't expected").

To retrieve **all trailing arguments** you need to set [`.multiple(true)`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.1/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.multiple) on the last argument (in your case "command") so it parses all the remaining arguments.
Additionally set the following options on the clap command to avoid parsing remaining arguments as clap arguments:

- [`.setting(AppSettings::TrailingVarArg)`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.1/clap/enum.AppSettings.html#variant.TrailingVarArg): to indicate that clap should stop parsing for other flags/options after the last positional argument.
- [`.setting(AppSettings::AllowLeadingHyphen)`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.1/clap/enum.AppSettings.html#variant.AllowLeadingHyphen): to allow argument values with leading hyphens like `-al`.

Here's an example:

```
let matches = App::new("foo")
    .version("0.1")
    .setting(clap::AppSettings::TrailingVarArg)
    .setting(clap::AppSettings::AllowLeadingHyphen)
    .arg(
        Arg::with_name("user")
            .short("u")
            .long("user")
            .required(true)
            .takes_value(true),
    )
    .arg(
        Arg::with_name("command")
            .help("The command to run")
            .required(true)
            .takes_value(true)
            .multiple(true),
    )
    // parse as if program ran as:   foo -u paul ls -al
    .get_matches_from(&["foo", "-u", "paul", "ls", "-al"]);

let command: Vec<&str> = matches.values_of("command").unwrap().collect();
println!("{:?}", command); // ["ls", "-al"]
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=353a5238fcfff611f85103619be1c1a1)

Comment: Works partially, so if you try something with flags doesn't work, unfortunately, 

e.g.: `foo -u jack ls -al` fails because of the `-al` at the end.

Comment: @MarceloBoeira To distinguish arguments from options, you can use a double dash `--`, after which none of the arguments will be interpreted as options: `foo -u jack -- ls -al`. It might also be able to tell clap to not parse options after the first non-option argument, but I'm not certain about that.

Comment: I'm actually considering dropping clap, because it seems easier to do it without it, do something like

`foo user command`

Comment: @MarceloBoeira Looking over the documentation, it looks like [`.setting(AppSettings::TrailingVarArg)`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/enum.AppSettings.html#variant.TrailingVarArg) does exactly that.

Comment: It's not that simple, the Trailing VarArg allows that, but you still have to do some parsing yourself...

Comment: Using both [`AppSettings::TrailingVarArg`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.1/clap/enum.AppSettings.html) and [`AllowLeadingHyphen`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.1/clap/enum.AppSettings.html#variant.AllowLeadingHyphen) it's possible to parse remaining args like `-al` without using `--`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of the current `clap` version (3.2.12), the above code is no longer valid since the API has gone through some changes plus deprecations. For e.g.

1. `short` now accepts a `char` instead of a `&str`
2. `with_name` is now
   deprecated and replaced with `new`
3. `setting` is now deprecated in
   favor of specific function names for each configuration
4. `multiple`
   now replaced by `multiple_values`
5. `values_of` deprecated in favor of `get_many`

The updated snippet is:

```
#[test]
fn test_parse_config() {
    let matches = App::new("foo")
        .version("0.1")
        .allow_hyphen_values(true)
        .trailing_var_arg(true)
        .arg(
            Arg::new("user")
                .short('u')
                .long("user")
                .required(true)
                .takes_value(true),
        )
        .arg(
            Arg::new("command")
                .help("The command to run")
                .required(true)
                .takes_value(true)
                .multiple_values(true)
        )
        // parse as if program ran as:   foo -u paul ls -al
        .get_matches_from(&["foo", "-u", "paul", "ls", "-al"]);

    let command: Vec<&str> = matches.get_many::<String>("command").unwrap().
        map(|s| s.as_str()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", command); // ["ls", "-al"]
}
```